# How can I retrieve data from dictionary to table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to write my firebase data to a table. I have some data which contains some order information. I have different orders so firstly I need make a big dictionary to reach all my order's data in one dictionary secondly I have to write that data to a Qt table. I tried a lot of way but I didn't solve it. Here is my data sample:

```
{'Pantolon': 9, 'adres': {'siparis alinma adresi': 'Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185', 'siparis edilme adresi': 'Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185'}, 'isim': {'username': 'Batuhan dinç'}, 'tarih': {'teslim alinma tarihi': {'alinma saati': '', 'alinma tarihi': '07/11/2019'}, 'teslim edilme tarihi': {'alinma tarihi': '14/11/2019', 'teslim saati': '18:00 - 19:00'}}, 'toplam tutar': {'toplam paket tutari': 146.20000000000002}, 'urun adetleri': {'adetler': [9]}}
{'Bluz': 6, 'adres': {'siparis alinma adresi': 'Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185', 'siparis edilme adresi': 'Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185'}, 'isim': {'username': 'Batuhan dinç'}, 'tarih': {'teslim alinma tarihi': {'alinma saati': '18:00 - 19:00', 'alinma tarihi': '08/11/2019'}, 'teslim edilme tarihi': {'alinma tarihi': '13/11/2019', 'teslim saati': '10:00 - 11:00'}}, 'toplam tutar': {'toplam paket tutari': 134.3}, 'urun adetleri': {'adetler': [1, 6]}, 'İpek bluz': 1}
{'Bluz': 1, 'adres': {'siparis alinma adresi': 'Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185', 'siparis edilme adresi': 'Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185'}, 'isim': {'username': 'Batuhan dinç'}, 'tarih': {'teslim alinma tarihi': {'alinma saati': '', 'alinma tarihi': ''}, 'teslim edilme tarihi': {'alinma tarihi': '09/11/2019', 'teslim saati': '18:00 - 19:00'}}, 'toplam tutar': {'toplam paket tutari': 44.8}, 'urun adetleri': {'adetler': [1, 1]}, 'İpek bluz': 1}
{'Bluz': 1, 'adres': {'siparis alinma adresi': 'Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185', 'siparis edilme adresi': 'Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185'}, 'isim': {'username': 'Batuhan dinç'}, 'tarih': {'teslim alinma tarihi': {'alinma saati': '', 'alinma tarihi': ''}, 'teslim edilme tarihi': {'alinma tarihi': '09/11/2019', 'teslim saati': '18:00 - 19:00'}}, 'toplam tutar': {'toplam paket tutari': 44.8}, 'urun adetleri': {'adetler': [1, 1]}, 'İpek bluz': 1}
```

How can I write this data to Qt table ?

```
firebase = Firebase(config)

db = firebase.database()

all_users = db.child("orders").child("kullanicilar").get()

for user in all_users.each():
    userArray.append(user.val())

for h in userArray:
    adresDict.update(h)


for lav in adresDict.values():
    print(lav)
```

Using the code you see in the above, I tried update dictionary according to that but its not working also I tried some enumaration but its also not solving my problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? Have you tried anything?

Comment: you say you tried a lot of things but didnt work.....show what you tried and tell what didnt work...

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I edited my question. I hope its become more clear.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have multiple dictionaries in your questions.

To access (or to fetch data) to each one you have to use `.items()`

```
for key, value in adresDict.items():
    print value.keys()[key]
```

Comment: _AttributeError: 'FirebaseResponse' object has no attribute 'items'_ I have that error.

Comment: The data that you printed from wich variable is it coming?
your code is not clear and missing some parts

Comment: I made it with  `adresDict.items()` and its working but I have to write all these from here to table...